# How to use matrices to rotate two matrix to specific positions while keeping their relative position unchanged?

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

Suppose there are two vectors $\overrightarrow{a}, \overrightarrow{b}$ that define a plane. How do I find matrices that can be applied to both verctors, so that $\overrightarrow{a}$ will be rotated to the positive part of x-axis, and $\overrightarrow{b}$ will be rotated to the I,II quadrant of x-y plane, without changing their length and the angle between them, a.k.a $|\overrightarrow{a}|, |\overrightarrow{b}|,  \overrightarrow{a} \cdot \overrightarrow{b}$ remain unchanged.

For example, if $\overrightarrow{a}=(1,1,1), \overrightarrow{b}=(1,-1,0)$, how do I find matrices that can transform $\overrightarrow{a}$ to$(\sqrt{3}, 0, 0)$, and $\overrightarrow{b}$ to $(0,\sqrt{2},0)$ ?

I try to implement such transform with Python so it would be good to find an efficient and numerical stable method to solve out the matrix.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can get $\vec b$ in the first quadrant only if the angle between $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ is less than $90^\circ$.

The idea is to start by creating an orthonormal set of vectors out of $\vec a$ and $\vec b$:

- normalize $\vec a$:
  $$\vec a_0=\frac{\vec a}{|\vec a|}$$
- create a perpendicular vector to the original plane, using cross product:
  $$\vec c=\vec a\times\vec b$$
- normalize $\vec c$:
  $$\vec c_0=\frac{\vec c}{|\vec c|}$$
- get the vector in the original plane, perpendicular to $\vec a$:
  $$\vec b_0=\vec c_0\times\vec a_0$$
  Note that this is already normalized, since $\vec a_0$ and $\vec c_0$ are perpendicular unit vectors.

Now the transformation matrix will rotate $\vec a_0$ to $\hat x$, $\vec b_0$ to $\hat y$, and $\vec c_0$ to $\hat z$. If we write the vectors in terms of components, we have $$M\begin{pmatrix}a_{0x} & b_{0x} & c_{0x}\\a_{0y} & b_{0y} & c_{0y}\\a_{0z} & b_{0z} & c_{0z}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
So from here, multiply on the right with the inverse of the second matrix, and you get the answer:
$$M=\begin{pmatrix}a_{0x} & b_{0x} & c_{0x}\\a_{0y} & b_{0y} & c_{0y}\\a_{0z} & b_{0z} & c_{0z}\end{pmatrix}^{-1}$$

**EDIT:** Here is a simple python script. You need to check the magnitudes of $a$ and $c$, and raise an error if they are too small

```
import numpy as np

def transf(a,b):
    a0=a/np.sqrt(np.dot(a,a))
    c=np.cross(a,b)
    c0=c/np.sqrt(np.dot(c,c))
    b0=np.cross(c0,a0)
    abc=np.array([a0,b0,c0]).T
    return np.linalg.inv(abc)
    
a=np.array([1,1,1])
b=np.array([1,-1,0])
M=transf(a,b)
print(M.dot(a), M.dot(b))
```

Comment: You are right, b should be allowed be rotated to I or II quadrant.

Comment: Is there a named for such transform? I try to do this with python so I guess I need to find a efficient and numerical stable method to get it done.

Comment: As long as the angle between $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ is not close to $0^\circ$ or $180^\circ$, you will have no problem. Numpy library has `dot` (to calculate the magnitude take the square root of the dot product of a vector with itself), `cross`, and `linalg.inv` methods. Not sure if it has a particular name.

Comment: Thanks for your kind support! Your solution reminds me of Gram–Schmidt process. That should be good enough for my use case.